# Compare arraylist item and get last index of each common object

Tags: java, android

I have json object type `ArrayList`, and i want to get last item of specific id from arraylist. Suppose `ArrayList` contains 3 object of id 1 and two object of id 2 ,so how can i get last object of id1 and last object of id 2.

Here is `ArrayList`

```
id-1,name-one,msg-hello,
id-1,name-one,msg-how,
id-2,name-one,msg-hi,
id-1,name-one,msg-are,
id-2,name-one,msg-test
id-1,name-one,msg-you
```

Now my requirement is to get below `ArrayList` ,that has last `jsonObject` of id 2 and id 1.

```
id-2,name-one,msg-test,
id-1,name-one,msg-you
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can use a

```
Hashmap<String, ArrayList<Model>>
```

Where the String is 'id'

(Model class has 2 variables, 1.Name, 2. msg)
If the id is already present in the hashmap, just Create a new model, assign values and append it in the arraylist correnponding to that id  else, insert a new id in the hashmap and create a new arraylist with a new model and add it to the hashmap.

Now to get the last element corresponding to every id is simple, 
just iterate through the hashmap and take the last element for each array list, Simple right? 
If you dont understand, let me know, i'll try to add some code.

Comment: It would be great help,if you'll add some code,if you can.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you could use [`Array<out T>.takeLastWhile { id == "id-1" || id == "id-2" }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/take-last-while.html)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by combining the [`reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#reversed()) method that was added in Java 21 with streams.  Assuming the objects in the list have a `getId()` method that return the ID:

```java
Object last = list.reversed().stream()
        .filter(o -> o.getId() == 1)
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow();
```